# Matching map with specs2

Tags: scala, specs2

Suppose I have a function `foo: () -> Map[String, A]`, where `A` is trait.

```
trait A { def x: Int, def y: Int }
```

Now I need to write a `specs2` spec to make sure that `foo` returns a map with two expected pairs. Note that I don't know the actual type of the values.

Unfortunately I didn't figure out how to use [havePairs](http://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Matchers.html) matcher in this case, so I am writing:

```
"test foo" in {
   val m = foo()
   def test(a: A, x: Int, y: Int) = (a.x must_== 0) and (a.y must_== 1)
   test(m("key1"), 0, 1)  
   test(m("key2"), 3, 5)
 }
```

This code is ugly. How would you suggest change it?

I guess I should write a custom *matcher* for `A` and new `havePairs` matcher, which would use this `A`-matcher to match the pairs values. Does it make sense ?

Comment: test(map("key1), 0, 1)  is no valid scala code. Did you miss something while pasting? Defining a **val map** is dangerous as it can get mixed up with the often used function **map**.

Comment: Do you want the test to work for the *trait A* or is a meant to be a *type parameter* ?

Comment: I want to test only the _trait A_. No type parameter needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would use **havePairs** because of the use of Traits you can not use the normal **contains** method which is based on **hashCode**.

Scala supports no structural Equality out of the box for class comparission. If you use **case classes** you get that feature and could use the **havePairs**.

If you need to support Traits I fear you are stuck with having to code what being Equal means for each individual case you want to support and test.

```
class ExampleSpec extends Specification{override def is: Fragments = s2"""
Generated map contains data                            $caseClassTest
works also for Trait                                   $traitTest
"""

  trait A { def x: Int ; def y: Int }

  // case class, exactly the same as Trait A
  case class CaseA(x: Int, y:Int) extends A

  // generates a Map with Traits on calling apply on function
  def generateTraitMap : () => Map[String,A] = () => Map(
    "k1" -> new A{ def x = 1 ; def y = -1 },
    "k2" -> new A{ def x = 0 ; def y = 42 }
  )

  // generates a Map with CaseClasses on calling apply on function
  def generateCaseClassMap : () => Map[String,A] = () => Map(
    "k1" -> CaseA(1, -1),
    "k2" -> CaseA(0,42)
  )

  // Test with case classes works with havePairs out of the box
  def caseClassTest = generateCaseClassMap() must havePairs(
    "k1" -> CaseA(1, -1),
    "k2" -> CaseA(0,42)
  )

  // testing Traits needs some plumbing, and will give poor error feedback
  def traitTest = {
    val data = generateTraitMap()
    def testStructuralEquality(a: A, b: A) = 
      List[A => Int]( _.x, _.y ).forall(f => f(a) == f(b) )

    val testData = Map(
      "k1" -> new A{ def x = 1 ; def y = -1 },
      "k2" -> new A{ def x = 0 ; def y = 42 }
    )

    testData.forall{ case (k,v) => testData.contains(k) && testStructuralEquality(v, testData(k)) } must beTrue

  }
```

}